# Join table on multiple criteria condition based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

```
select
  a.Name
  a.Year
  a.Month
  a.Day
  b.Price
into #test_table
from #tableA as a
left join #tableB as b on
   a.Name = b.Name
   and a.Year = b.Year
   and a.Month = b.Month
   and a.Day = b.Day
```

There are instances where Month and/or Day may be missing from table B and I was trying to find a way to only join on available values (e.g. only on Name and Year, when Month and Day are null or blank). I was thinking that a case-when approach might be optimal; however, when I try the approach below I get "incorrect syntax near '='" and "incorrect syntax near 'else'"

```
select
  a.Name
  a.Year
  a.Month
  a.Day
  b.Price
into #test_table
from #tableA as a
left join #tableB as b on
   case when a.Month = '' then a.Name = b.Name and a.Year = b.Year
   else a.Name = b.Name and a.Year = b.Year and a.Month = b.Month and a.Day = b.Day
```

I don't want to exclude the records when Month or Day is Null/blank.

What am I missing?

What is correct?

Comment: That's not valid approach, but you can always do:  `and a.Day = ISNULL(b.Day, a.Day)`. Just make sure some of the values aren't nulls so you don't get a big ol' cross join

Comment: `case` is an *expression*, it returns a scalar value, not another expression. Do not use `isnull` in a join expression it's not sargable, use standard and/or logic.

Comment: @siggemannen would this exclude the records if Day is null? I don't want to exclude the records

Comment: Nope, it wouldn't, since you fallback to a.day = a.day which always is true. Give it a try

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  a.Name
  a.Year
  a.Month
  a.Day
  b.Price

into #test_table
from #tableA as a
left join #tableB as b on
   a.Name = b.Name and a.Year = b.Year
   and (b.Month is null or a.Month = b.Month)
   and (b.Day is null or a.Day = b.Day);
```